# Accessing a hyperlink from a SQL query

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql

I have a react application linked up to a PostgreSQL database. I'm using pgAdmin to insert my data. I have many rows but one of the fields in the row contains a link, and I want to be able access this link in my react application. Example query:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET body='Learn about React <a href=""https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)"" target=""_blank"">here</a>'
WHERE ID = 1;
```

I have no issues displaying my data in react but it displays the HTML tags, which is not what I want.

Am I going about this the right way? Or should I remove the hyper link from the query and create an algorithm or regex expression to search for word `here` and attach `<a href>` tags to it?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml. Although I wouldn't recommand to generate HTML from your sql query.

Comment: Okay, so dangerouslysetinnerhtml is only good if I leave the HTML in my SQL query? Can you recommend another way of inserting a hyperlink in my query?

Comment: I guess it depends on your app, and maybe you don't have the choice. How is your content generated ?

Comment: I'm am setting the database data to an object, and then I am iterating through that object and displaying each field in its own div. `return ( <div>{body}</div>)`

Comment: And what are your motivations for using a database to store that content? Is this content going to change a lot overtime ? Will some users be able to change that content, or will you be the only one, as the administrator I presume, be able to change that content ?

Comment: Yeah its probably going to be updated a lot. The main reason I'm using the database is to get some experience with using PostgreSQL. Probably not the best reason. I was just hoping there was an easy way to do this. What do you recommend I use if I'm going to be using lots of links in my data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195132/discussion-between-nubinub-and-learnerforlife).